# AWS lambda function error - Unable to import module 'index': Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a lambda in nodejs. Following the documentation, I have created a zip file with lambda function, node_modules and package.json. The structure of my lambda zip file is as follows:

```
my-lambda-function/
|
|---util/
|     |
|     |--util-1.js
|     |--util-2.js
|---api/
|     |
|     |--api-call-1.js
|     |--api-call-2.js    
|
|---config
|     |
|     |--env/
|     | |--env-file-1.js
|     |
|     |--config-file-1.js
|     |--config-file-2.js
|
|---node_modules/
|     |
|     |--module-1/
|     |--module-2/
|---index.js
|---package.json
```

For creating the this zip file I'm using a gulp task,

```
gulp.task('zip', ['test'], () => {
 const buildArtifact = ['index.js', 'package.json', 'util/**', 
 'config/**', 'api/**'];
 Object.keys(pjson.dependencies).forEach((dep) => {
  buildArtifact.push(`node_modules/${dep}/**/*`);
 });
 const zipFile = `${pjson.name}.zip`;
 return gulp.src(buildArtifact, { base: '.' })
   .pipe(zip(zipFile))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

This lambda is running locally with lambda-local. But while testing this lambda is throwing error

```
Unable to import module 'index': Error
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/ioredis/built/utils/lodash.js:2:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
```

Current error is pointing to ioredis module (which is available in node_modues folder), but if I remove the usage of ioredis from the code (by removing the imports for ioredis) then the error changes to another node module.

It seems my lambda function is unable to load/find the node_modules. 
Is it due to lambda is failing to install npm?

Any pointers to solve this would be helpful as we are struggling with this for a few days

Thanks

### More details

1. We can reproduce the error by deleting the node_modules folder and then running the lambda locally
2. If I remove all my dependencies, a trivial logging statement will work.
3. The lambda is using node 8.10 in aws

### Answer (@Kannaiyan)

Changing the zip task to:

```
gulp.task('npm-install', () => gulp.src('./package.json')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
  .pipe(install({ production: true })));
```

worked for me.

Comment: You need to upload `node_module` too when deploying your lambda. It seems your lodash needs a module which exist in your machine but not inside your application node_module.

Comment: I'm not using lodash in my function directly. But seems it is being referenced from ioredis.

Comment: there might be some module using `lodash` and `lodash` using other NPM module not in your node_module. When we run application this is how search for NPM module goes first your directory `__dirname/node_modules` , then `../node_modules`, this will continue till `root` directory of machine. Thus no error when testing locally as this flow can happen, however in AWS lambda, that module is simply not available. Just delete all your modules and reinstall them.

Comment: Thanks Navin. I'm uploading a zip file manually through AWS console for the time being. In the zip file I can see all the the required npms in node_modules folder. Can you please describe a bit more  -  "delete all your modules and reinstall them"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unable to import module 'index': Error

It looks like some of your dependencies are installed / not packaged correctly. Delete the node_modules directory and re-install the module with `npm install` should fix the issue.

Make sure your function get packaged as mentioned in the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

If your bundle missed a node_module, then it will result in this error.

**EDIT1:**

You got an issue with gulp packaging.

The following example has the complete documentation for packaging lambda with gulp.

https://medium.com/@AdamRNeary/a-gulp-workflow-for-amazon-lambda-61c2afd723b6

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm already doing this. node_modules is inside the zip file I'm uploading. All the packages form the dependecy section of my package.json are there in the node_modules folder. I'm using the gulp zip task to create the zip file

Comment: I have updated some more details in my question so that someone else can use it

Answer (score 0):

Also got this error when creating an **AWS::Serverless::Function** using CloudFormation, and specifying the code with `InlineCode`, where the code referenced a dependency that was not bundled in the selected Runtime.

Note that some packages *are* included in the runtime (eg. nodejs8.10 seems to have at least aws-sdk and util).